# Unable to retrive data from some rows in google form spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have tried this script to extract row data into an array. 
Data from the first two columns were able to extract but for remaining columns data collected is showing as "undefined". Can any one guide me the error taken place in my script?

The same is tried in other sheets and this works well, but not the form based spreadsheet ?
Can any one pull out the error behind this script

```js
function sendEmails3() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Issues");
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows  = sheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3)

      // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
      var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var message_body2= new Array();
  var message_body1 =    " <html> <body> <table> <tbody>" 
      +"<tr>    <th> Timestamp </th> "
      +"    <th>    Program</th> "
      +"    <th>    District</th> "
      +"    <th>    Type to Issue</th> "
      +"    <th>    Name</th> "
      +"    <th>    Mobile Number</th> "
      +"    <th>    Personal Mail ID</th> "
      +"    <th>    Issue Description (not more that 100 words) if more, Kindly mail to ap_admin@drreddysfoundation.org</th> "
      +"    <th>    Share us the duration, since how many days the issue persist. ( in DAYS)</th> "
      +"    <th>    Center Mail ID</th> "
      +"    <th>    Issue Addressed</th> "
      +"    <th>    Issue Addressed Date</th> ";

  var message_body3 =   "</tbody> </table> </body> </html>";

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var timeStamp = row[0];  // timestamp column
    var addressedDate = row[11];

    if (addressedDate != "" && timeStamp != "") {  // Prevents sending duplicates

      message_body2[i] = "</tr> <tr> "
        +"  <td>" + row[0] + "</td> "
        +"  <td> "+ row[1] + " </td> "
        +"  <td> "+ row[2] + " </td> "
        +"  <td> "+ row[3] + " </td> "
        +"  <td> "+ row[4] + " </td> "
        +"  <td> "+ row[5] + " </td> "
        +"  <td> "+ row[6] + " </td> "
        +"  <td> "+ row[7] + " </td> "
        +"  <td> "+ row[8] + " </td> "
        +"  <td> "+ row[9] + " </td> "
        +"  <td> "+ row[10]+ " </td> "
        +"  <td> "+ row[11]+ " </td> "
        +"  <td> "+ row[12]+ " </td> " + "</tr> " ; 
    }
    Browser.msgBox( row[2] + " - " + row[3] + " - " + row[4] + " - " +  row[5] + " - " + row[6] + " - " + row[7] + "  - " + row[8] + "  - " + row[9] + " - " + row[10]+ " - " + row[11]+ " - " + row[12]);
  }
  var complete_message = message_body1 + message_body2+ message_body3;

  // check data accumulated
  Browser.msgBox(complete_message);  

  // export to a cell all the extracted data to verifiy  
  sheet.getRange(i, 3).setValue(complete_message);
}
```

[Click here to view the script & spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjkkHlm3kCphdC1CTHV6RkhlYjFaQklSa0U4RTJmcXc&pli=1#gid=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are a couple different errors that are causing your problems.

First, you have your startRow set to 2, but row 2 in your spreadsheet is blank. You should either start with row 3 or delete row 2.

Second, this line says to only include 3 columns:

```
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3)
```

That last argument, 3, is the number of columns in your data range. So if you want all columns to  be included, it should be 12. Or, you could use sheet.getLastColumn().

Comment: Also, when using numRows=getLastRow() you get the total number of rows, if you start from row2 you should use numRows-1 to get valid data (because 3rd argument is relative to the starting point).